# Number of ways to deal to deal 5 cards to 5 players from a 52 card deck

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

I have already seen this question asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1988403/number-of-ways-to-deal-5-cards-to-5-players-from-a-52-card-deck). My first attempt of solving it was the same as the accepted answer, however I tried to make the calculation simpler by realizing that there are $\binom{52}{25}$ ways to select 25 cards from the deck and for each of these are $\binom{25}{5}$ ways to distribute them, thus the number of ways to deal 5 cards to 5 players would be

$$
\binom{52}{25} \cdot \binom{25}{5}
$$

But this does not equal the correct answer, $\frac{52!}{(5!)^527!}$. Why is this?

Comment: I really think that there are rather more that $\binom{25}5$ ways to "distribute" these $25$ cards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your answer is wrong because $_{25}C_5$ is not the number of ways to distribute $25$ cards among $5$ players... that is the number of ways to deal $5$ cards out of $25$ cards to one player. To solve this you need to use the "partitions formula". The number of ways to partition $n$ objects into groups of $g_1, g_2,..., g_k$ groups where $g_1+g_2+...+g_k=n$ is
$$\frac{n!}{g_1!g_2!...g_k!}$$
so instead of $_{25}C_5$ you will have
$$\frac{25!}{5!5!5!5!5!}$$
and your final answer should end up being
$$\frac{52!}{25!27!}*\frac{25!}{5!5!5!5!5!}$$
$$\frac{52!}{(5!)^527!}$$

Comment: About $2.98×10^{29} $.